# How to validate first name Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I am trying to validate a first name in Objective-C. Please note that the name can contain spaces and only letter.

Here my code that is not working:

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"^[A-Z][a-z]*[\\s{L}\\s{M}\\s{Nl}][A-Z][a-z]*$";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
BOOL isValid = [nameTest evaluateWithObject:name];
return isValid;
```

Comment: what does this mean? "bname can contain spaces and only letter."

Comment: I know this is old, but... obligatory article: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Also, this requirement doesn't even match simple compound names like "Jean-Luc".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it :

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"[a-zA-z]+([ '-][a-zA-Z]+)*$";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
BOOL isValid = [nameTest evaluateWithObject:name];
return isValid;
```

Comment: The parameters name might confusing  - the question is about first name validation, and the param names refer email validation.

Answer (score 1):

This method works for me:

```
-(BOOL)validate:(NSString *)string
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z ]" options:0 error:&error];    
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];        
    return numberOfMatches == string.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code

```
NSString *yourstring = @"hello";

NSString *Regex = @"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*";
NSPredicate *TestResult = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",Regex];

if ([TestResult evaluateWithObject:yourstring] == true)
{

    // validation passed
}
else
{
// invalid name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate the full name, the code is this:

```
- (BOOL)isFullNameValid: (NSString *) name {

NSString *nameRegex = @"^[A-Za-z]+(?:\\s[A-Za-z]+)*$";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
BOOL isValid = [nameTest evaluateWithObject:name];
return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BOOL check=NO;
for(int i=0;i<[txt.text length];i++)
{
if([txt.text characterAtIndex:i]<=64 && [txt.text characterAtIndex:i]>=33)
{
    check=YES;

}else if([txt.text characterAtIndex:i]<=122 && [txt.text characterAtIndex:i]>=65)
{
    if([txt.text characterAtIndex:i]<=96 && [txt.text characterAtIndex:i]>=91)
    {
        check=YES;

    }

}
}
if(check==YES)
{
    [self alert:@"Name Contain spetial character"];
    return NO;

}else
{
    [self alert:@"Name Inserted succesfully"];

    return YES;
}
return  NO;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 func nameValidation() -> Bool {
    let RegEx = "[a-zA-Z ]{2,15}"
    let name = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", RegEx)
    return name.evaluate(with: self)
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Explain what you are doing. And, for that matter... 2-15 characters? That's very arbitrary. And I'm fairly sure your lack of boundaries in the regex makes it just match anything _containing_ that, meaning it basically does not put any restrictions on the content except "contains at least two letters in a row.